# Open a Sparx Enterprise Architect (EA) 13 model at a specific location

Tags: command-line, hyperlink, enterprise-architect

In order to make Enterprise Architect more popular in my organization, I would like to be able to send "EA links" to other members, so that they can start working directly on a given diagram or folder of the Project Browser.

Ideally, a link that I could embed in a document, such as ea://path/to/diagram/Diagram1 would be perfect. But I haven't heard of that feature.

In a lot of treeview-based applications, it is possible to provide command-line arguments to tell the application the treeview node to display initially. But I cannot find any documentations about the EA.exe command line (EA.exe /help does not do anything).

Does such a feature exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a diagram as default. How and where varies between different EA versions (they shift menus for each release). For EA13 you can use the context menu at a blank position of the diagram: *Set as User Default*.

I could not find the Model Default option back in EA's option jungle. However, when typing "default" in the Start menu of V13 it comes up with

[image]

which triggers the behavior. FWIW: there is no un-setting for this. You have to create a dummy diagram, make it model default and delete it. Now, that's a smart user interfaces, isn't it?

Setting a default element in focus is (AFAIK) only possible via scripting. The best would be to have an add-in that issues a `Repository.ShowInProjectBrowser(element)` on opening a model. Alternatively you can have a `.bat`-script to do that for you.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, to say the least, I have not been amazed by EA's user interface so far :)

Comment: A long time ago I coined the acronym EAUI: EA Unique Interface. That time there was a bit of fun behind it. But honestly, it krept steadily towards madness :-/

Answer (score 0):

There is actually an open source tool [EA Protocol Handler](https://sourceforge.net/p/eaprotocol/wiki/Home/) that does exactly this.

> The EA Protocol Handler is a program, targeting the Windows operating system, that defines and handles an ea:// protocol to link from web pages to specific artifacts in Enterprise Architect repositories.

I tested this many years ago, and it worked. The reason I didn't use it any further was the fact that it made uri's too long to use as hyperlink in Word.

It seems to have been dormant since 2009, but it might still work.